# Javascript Cookie remove or delete with regex (Regular Expression)

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies, session-cookies

[image: Cookies to remove or delete with regex]

[image: The Cookie is Not Returned in the normal document.cookie function]

This is a site i want remove or delete the last 5 cookies starting with "search"  with javascript Regex (Regular expression) how do i do it

The Cookie is Not Returned in the normal document.cookie function

i tried a lot of tricks and codes and not working... please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//to get all the cookies 
var cookiesArray = document.cookie.split(";"); <br>
//loop through the array and check if the cookie name is what we want
for(var i = 0; i < cookiesArray.length; i++)
{
    //remove if any extra space
    var cookie = cookiesArray[i].trim();
    //to get the cookie name
    var cookieName = cookie.split("=")[0];

    // If the prefix of the cookie's name matches the one specified(i.e search), remove it
    if(cookieName.indexOf("search") === 0) {

        // Remove the cookie
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;";
    }
}
```

Comment: the Cookie is not even returned with normal "document.cookie" function.it is present in the array returned from "document.cookie" function

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
    function deleteCookie(name) {
        document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + (new Date(0)).toUTCString() + ";";
    };
    function findCookies(name) {
        var r=[];
        document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("("+name + "[^= ]*) *(?=\=)", "g"), function(a, b, ix){if(/[ ;]/.test(document.cookie.substr(ix-1, 1))) r.push(a.trim());})
        return r;
    };
```

Usage:

```
findCookies("search").forEach(function(fullName){deleteCookie(fullName);});
```

or use this, **if** you need only 5 of them (from last):

```
findCookies("search").slice(-5).forEach(function(fullName){deleteCookie(fullName);});
```

Comment: the Cookie is not even returned with normal "document.cookie" function.it is present in the array returned from "document.cookie" function